# Is there where to do line breaks in the expression builder of azure data flow?

Tags: line-breaks, azure-data-factory, expressionbuilder

I am using the Expression Builder of Derived Column setting of the Azure Data Flow Activity. I am trying to code ac line break. So it looks like:

Value1
Value2

What is the syntax to code this?

Comment: Hi @Dimeji Olayinka. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'\n'` to code ac line break in the DerivedColumn.

In my case, I use `concat(Column1,concat('\n',Column2))` epression to concat two columns.
[image]

So I get the results, the Column3 looks like:
Value1 Value2

[image]